# get return value from function in a class in variable python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

i am beginner in python . I have created a file series.py which has class name Modulus . Under which there is function defined name mod. it return all divisible number till 100. i am calling this function from another python file name newone.py.

```
series.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

class Modulus:
        def mod(inp):
                list1 = list(range(1,101))
                #print(list)
                list2 = []
                for num in list1:
                        abc = num % inp
                        if ( abc == 0 ):
                                list2.append(num)
                return list2
```

And

```
newone.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from series import Modulus
inp = int(input("Please enter number from 1-10:"))

obj = Modulus()

result = obj.mod(inp)

print(result)
```

i am trying to get return value in result varible. But when i try to print this variable i got error as below.

```
Please enter number from 1-10:4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./newone.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = obj.mod(inp)
TypeError: mod() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

i am not getting where i am wrong . Please help me out.

Comment: in mod method, self is missing.... mod(self, inp)

Comment: Thanks a lot @AriGold . It is working. Can you tell me why it is needed.

Comment: Welcome, this will be your task for today, search, read, try and try again, the answer is only a google search away...